# Editing list view contents looses the position of scroll

Tags: android, android-listview

In my app theres a screen where i display a custom ListView with title and edit icon. When a click is made on edit icon of the row of `ListView`, a dialog box opens up where the title can be edited. The issue is once the title is saved, the `ListView` scrolls to the bottom of the page.

I am using `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the onclicklistener of the save button of dialogue box.
Is there a way to maintain the scroll position of the `ListView`? as I am not creating a new instance of the adapter and assigning the arraylist to the adapter in the onclicklistener.

Comment: Found the issue. I had set android:transcriptMode as "autoscroll" for list view in main activity's xml file. Changed the attribute to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I think after you done your editing you can use `setSelection(position)` to maintain the position